# Limit Usage of Python Script to One Particular Computer?

Tags: python, limit

How should one generally go about limiting the usage of a script to one particular computer for a single, average computer user?

Comment: average computer user is a vague term to base any sort of answers on.

Comment: Non-programmer, or, rather, user with limited knowledge of programming in general, would perhaps be better terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tie the script to the MAC address of your computer by using `uuid.getnode()`, which returns the MAC address.  Then in your script you would have

```
import uuid
if uuid.getnode() != #precomputed number:
    raise SystemExit()
```

You'll need to change the permissions of the script to make sure it can't be edited.

Comment: permission can be overwritten. OR it can be copied, and pasted without that block of  code.

Comment: But if it's compiled?

Comment: @taesu if the permission is set to `444` it's not super simple to copy.  I guess I'd say the average computer user couldn't do it.

Comment: @TheNovice I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by "if it's compiled."  Are you using py2exe or something on Windows?

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity of that comment.  It was in reference to, "what if you have only the compiled version? (.pyo extension) using something like py2exe, the exe file just a simple archive containing pyo files".  Would having the script "compiled" through py2exe help me in any way?

Comment: @TheNovice Nah, compiling the script doesn't tie it to a specific computer in any way.  It would make them harder to edit, but there are ways of getting source code back from compiled Python files.

Comment: @Code Piersall Thanks for your help!  By chance, do you think you could also link me to some sort of text explaining changing the permission to 444?

Answer (score 1):

May be you should limit running the script to the MAC address of that particular machine.

Comment: What if the user simply removes the line that checks the MAC address? Or even, Spoof the MAC address.

Comment: Why to give the source to the user, make it an .exe and give that. And considering that the "Average user" , I had given this solution, assuming that MAC address spoofing is out of reach.

Answer (score 0):

With limited knowledge, I don't think this is possible because you are giving a script.

Let's say function A is the function responsible for limiting the script to be run at a particular computer. Because python script is a editable script, one can just remove that block of code, namely function A, and run the rest of the code.

This might be possible in a compiled language,
but not particularly in scripting language such as python.

If, and only if you are dealing with an average non-programmer, then there are many many ways of achieving it, namely, making a internet connection to a home computer through the net.

Thus, taking control of the responsibility in determining if that particular computer is the computer that you allowed for the program to run on

```
if (connection.call_home):
    #run
else:
    #pass
```

Your home script would be:

```
if (incoming.ip == '123.456.789.101'):
    return true
else:
    return false
```

Comment: I see, thank you.  Do you happen to know of any way to make it incredibly hard for others to edit Python script?

Comment: what if you have only the compiled version? (.pyo extension) using something like py2exe, the exe file just a simple archive containing pyo files

Comment: You can do this: write 1000000 lines of code to hide your actual working code.